# How to find a duplicate word in the same word?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I need to write a code when given the string "**LEMONLEMONLEMO**"
I have to find the repetitive word and return: "**LEMON**"

Given "**APPLLEAPL**" return "**APLLE**".

It's given that the string is build form repetitiveness of the same word.

I'm just starting with Python, which make it harder for me to think how to address the problem.

Comment: It would be `LEMO` though, wouldnt it?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try matching on the following regex pattern:

```
(.*).*\1
```

This says to match and capture some number of characters, so long as the same group appears later in the input.

```
input = "LEMONLEMO"
result = re.match(r'(.*).*\1', input)
match = result.group(1)
print(match)

LEMO

res = re.match(match + '.*' + '(?=' + match + ')', input)
output = res.group(0)
print(output)

LEMON
```

The `(.*)` is greedy, so it should, by default, find the *longest* substring which also happens to repeat later on.

**Edit:**

To take into account your full requirements, after finding `LEMO`, we then need to take the full substring from the first match up to, but not including, the repeat occurrence of `LEMO`.  I use this regex pattern for that:

```
LEMO.*(?=LEMO)
```

The code appears a bit rough, because the above pattern needs to be built on the fly.

Comment: Just as a comment: we could use `re.findall` if we wanted to find all possible repeating matches.

Comment: This is great... So just to get how this works, \1 represents the first captured group?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have mentioned that.  `\1` represents the first (and only) capture group, which corresponds to whatever we captured in `(.*)` earlier in the pattern.  In some languages/tools, the first capture group is written as `$1`.

Comment: but what of I'm looking to fined "LEMON" and not the repetetive substring?

Comment: Then you need to redefine your question.  What is the string were `LEMONLANDMARK`.  Would `LEMON` still be the output only because the leading `L` appeared later in the string?

Comment: Well in that case the question just loses all its sense @raphael, under what criteria would you want to find `lemon`?

Comment: Delete the above comment and instead update your question and state the actual problem.

Comment: py throw me an expiation on result = re.match(r'(.*).*\1', input), AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'match'

Comment: I'm using py 3.x

Comment: [My script also seems to be working on Python 3.x](https://rextester.com/ZWGGE30052).

Comment: I forgot to import :/